# A Problem Involving an Inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

How to prove that  **$\frac1{a^2} + \frac1{b^2} + \frac1{c^2} \geq \frac1{ab} + \frac1{bc} + \frac1{ac}$**

Assume that given symbolic terms are *REAL* and *POSITIVE*

Comment: Keys to questions being well received: Try to use latex formatting and show some effort. Also is that second term on the LHS supposed to be $1/b^2$

Comment: Looks similar to AM GM inequality concept, though like 25 % similar...

Comment: Also looks like homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving all Terms to the left and cancelling the denominators your inequality is equivalent to
$$a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2\geq a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2$$
this is true, since we have
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+yz+zx$$ for all real numbers

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{ab}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{2}{ab}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right)=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)^2\geq0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note this also follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\right)^2 & = \left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{1}{a^2}\right) \\
 & \ge \left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca}\right)^2.
\end{align}

Then take the square root of each side.